# Viewing a closed subset in a Euclidean space as a submanifold in higher dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, transversality

By Manifolds I will just mean [smooth manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold) .

> If $C$ is any closed subset of $\Bbb R^k$, then show that $\exists$ a submanifold $X$ of $\Bbb R^{k+1}$ such that $X \cap \Bbb R^k = C$ .

I here assume the result from Analysis that $\exists$ a smooth map $g : \Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R$ such that $C = g^{-1}(0)$

Now if $g$ is regular at all points of $C$ (i.e. $dg_x : \Bbb R^k \to \Bbb R$ is surjective $\forall x \in C$ ) then, $C$ would have been a submanifold of $\Bbb R^k$ itself and hence $X$ could have just been the canonical inclusion of $C$ in $\Bbb R^{k+1}$ !

This is clearly not the case always!

So I'm trying to use $g$ to get a transversality argument.

Like I had thought of $h : \Bbb R^{k+1} \to \Bbb R$ defined by, $h(x_1,\dots,x_k,x_{k+1})=g(x_1,\dots,x_k) + x_{k+1}$ then clearly $h$ is transversal ro $\Bbb R$ but I am unable to keep track of $C$ as nothing can be assumed about the behaviour of $g$ outside  $C$ (except the fact that it is of course smooth there) .

Comment: I think I'm stuck right away. There is a smooth map $g\colon \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $g^{-1}(0)$ is, e.g. a Cantor set?

Comment: @RyleeLyman Yes such smooth functions exist and it is a theorem By Whitney. Anyway you can look at [Nate Eldredge's function](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179445/non-zero-smooth-functions-vanishing-on-a-cantor-set) for your query on Cantor set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so given our closed set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^k$, and taking a smooth function $g\colon \mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}$ with $C = g^{-1}(0)$, what if we take $X$ to be the graph of $g$, namely

$$X := \{ \left(x_1,\dotsc,x_k,g(x_1,\dotsc,x_k)\right) \mid (x_1,\dotsc,x_k) \in \mathbb{R}^k\}.$$

Since $g$ is smooth, it should be easy to check that $X$ is a $k$-dimensional embedded submanifold of  $\mathbb{R}^{k+1}$. Then the fact that $X\cap \mathbb{R}^k = C$ comes for free from our assumption on $g$.